# Can Private Data stored in SideDB be accessed by server administrators?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am setting up a Fabric application where fragments of symmetric encryption keys need to be stored on peers. Private Data is ideally suited to handle this. However, I am concerned whether network administrators of the peer nodes can access plain-text private data. Does anyone know whether this is possible and if so is there anything that could be done to prevent this?

Comment: what do you mean by plaintext ?

Comment: What I mean by 'plaintext' is basically unencrypted data. For instance, the data is probably encrypted using the peer's private key. In this case the question is: suppose I am the server administrator, can I obtain the private key and decrypt the encrypted private data to obtain 'plaintext' data that is meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assumed that a peer administrator has access to the file system where the peer stores data. In the case of private data, the private data is made available only to certain organization's peers and saved on the file system of these peers. The system administrator of these peers would therefore be able to access any plaintext private data.

That being said, some vendors that host Hyperledger Fabric as a service have protections in place such that the vendor is unable to access the peer's file system data.